# Add additional 8px to margin

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have 2 div, one is using position :absolute and another is using position : static (default)
the absolute position by left : 100px.
the static position by margin-left : 100px

Why they aren't the positions at same place?

[image: where is the 8px?]

Comment: Perhaps link to the fiddle, too?

Comment: Since you posted a screenshot of using a fiddle, could you post the fiddle link?  It's kind of hard to read the image text.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a link to the fiddle would be nice, but until then you could try setting:

```
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Since the absolutely positioned `div` has been taken out of the normal flow of the document, it is most likely that any inconsistencies between the placement of the static `div` and the absolute `div` are caused by `margin`'s or `padding`'s set on the elements containing the static `div`.

Comment: Yes! you are right, the 8px is added by body. the "absolute" position can position it without problem because of absolute. But the "static" position is affected by the body margin. By the way, why the body always add these 8px to margin? is it the browser problem? I using Chrome, ok I will try ie and firefox later.

Comment: It is `8px` in most browsers, it is set by the user agent style sheet,  [you can read about them here](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/), you could override those by adding a reset style sheet (but that would also override a lot of other default styles). The snippet I posted above resets the margins and the padding on `html` and `body` only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't the Border width of 2px all the way around (added up) to total 8px?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the body margin.

```
    body {
      margin:0px;
    }
```

The absolute div is a child of 'HTML'.  The static div is a child of 'Body'.  Body, by default, has an 8px margin.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y5S6W/

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements are displayed in the order they are coded into the page by default, the absolutely positioned div will be in a specific place; however, the 2nd div will be after the first div, which means that its CSS of margin left: 100px; actually moves it over 100px plus the width of the first div from the left side of the page.